# Gensim Word2Vec distances are too close

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am training my own word2vec model on Gensim in python, on a relatively small dataset. The data consist of about 3000 short-text entries from different people, most of which are two or three sentences. I know this is small for a word2vec dataset, but I've seen similar ones work in the past.

For some reason, when I train my model all of the features are impractically close to one another. For instance:

```
model.most_similar('jesus/NN')
[(u'person/NN', 0.9999418258666992),
 (u'used/VB', 0.9998890161514282),
 (u'so/RB', 0.9998359680175781),
 (u'question/NN', 0.9997845888137817),
 (u'just/RB', 0.9996646642684937),
 (u'other/NN', 0.9995589256286621),
 (u'allow/VB', 0.9995476603507996),
 (u'feel/VB', 0.9995381236076355),
 (u'attend/VB', 0.9995047450065613),
 (u'make/VB', 0.9994802474975586)]
```

The parts of speech are included because I lemmatize the data.

Here is my training code:

```
cleanedResponses = []
#For every response
for rawValue in df['QB17_W6'].values:
    lemValue = lemmatize(rawValue)
    cleanedResponses.append(lemValue)

df['cleaned_responses'] = cleanedResponses
bigram_transformer = Phrases(df.cleaned_responses.values)

model = Word2Vec(bigram_transformer[df.cleaned_responses.values], size=5)
```

This also happens when I train without the bigram transformer. Does anybody have an idea as to why the distances are so close?

Comment: Default `window` size in `Word2Vec` is 5. Are your sentences very short by any chance, so that entire sentence gets covered in window used for training an example?

Comment: That is a good point - yes, they can be as short as one word, but some are as long as a full sentence. Should the window size not exceed the minimum length? then it would be 1, which seems like it wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Not sure what your data contains but intuitively window size should make sense, that is, your context window should help predict what the center word is

Comment: Note that a sentence with 1 word is a no-op for training: there's no way to predict that word from its neighbors. There's no harm to using a larger window than than a text's length - it will just be essentially truncated to the number of available words in that direction. More suspicious in your setup is the tiny vector `size=5` – maybe that plus your small dataset (and often tiny sentences) is what's making all the end-vectors so similar.